# Create a valid MSI handle without opening an MSI

Tags: windows-installer

I would like to create MSI handle without opening an actual MSI? I am using C++ code.
Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,
Marc

Comment: The feature is very useful when writing code for unit-testing of custom actions or reproducing a bug at some alien machine.

Answer (score 0):

Same as getting a file handle without opening an actual file (or virtual file, etc.): create one. Call [MsiOpenDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370338.aspx) with `MSIDBOPEN_CREATE`. Note that if you need an Install handle instead of a Database handle (generally represented as `hInstall` instead of `hDatabase`) you have to do something which starts an installation session and this technique won't work.

However I'm guessing you didn't even want to create an MSI (even a temporary one you never save). If that's true, neither case is possible.